# Strange behavior with function overriding and optional params in Groovy

Tags: inheritance, groovy, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

The behavior is best explained with a little code. In this example calling `super.doSomething(t)` from class `y` without the optional parameter results in it recursively calling itself (`y.doSomething`). Is this a bug or is there a explanation why leaving off the optional param and calling super results in a recursive call.

You can try it out here: https://tio.run/#groovy

```
class x {
    void doSomething(Integer x, Boolean n=false){
        println("Super ${n}")
    }
}

class y extends x {
    @Override
    void doSomething(Integer t, Boolean q=true){
        println("Sub")
        super.doSomething(t)  //Stack overflow - super.doSomething calls the subclass
        super.doSomething(t, q)  //Works as expected
    }
}

new y().doSomething(4)
```

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://objectpartners.com/2015/09/02/groovy-gotcha-passing-zero-arguments-to-a-method-that-expects-one/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is basically what gets generated for what you have and this representation should help make sense of it:

```
class X {
    void doSomething(Integer x) {
        // remember that for an instance of Y, this is
        // going to call doSomething(Integer, Boolean) in
        // the subclass (Y), not this class (X).
        doSomething x, false
    }

    void doSomething(Integer x, Boolean n) {
        println("Super ${n}")
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    void doSomething(Integer t) {
        doSomething t, true
    }
    @Override
    void doSomething(Integer t, Boolean q){
        println("Sub")

        // stack overflow because this calls doSomething(Integer) in
        // the parent class which is going to call
        // doSomething(Integer, Boolean), which will end up right back here
        super.doSomething(t)

        // no stack overflow
        super.doSomething(t, q)
    }
}
```

Comment: The way default parameters work is the compiler generates overloaded methods like those shown in my code sample.

Comment: Even though it totally makes sense given the Java code generated, the behaviour looks like a bug to me. Though probably impossible to fix given that this behaviour is actually what you would expect in most cases.

Comment: @Renato "the behaviour looks like a bug to me" - It isn't a bug.  The generated code is consistent with how default parameters are documented and intended to work and the runtime dispatch is consistent with how polymorphic dispatch is supposed to work in both Groovy and Java.

Comment: To clarify, I mean that the behavior isn't a bug in the language or the runtime.  The written code is where the bug exists.

Comment: I didn't say it is a bug, but it "looks like" one. I think I would have thought the same as the OP, and most developers probably would think the same.

Comment: Let's call that a "quirk", not a bug.

Comment: @Renato "I didn't say it is a bug" - Agreed.  You said "looks like a bug to me".  I said "It isn't a bug".  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I would definitely call this a quirk but makes sense. Thanks for the explanation.